# Is there any significance of the triple underscores in this python for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions

Is there any significance in the triple underscore in Python?

This was in a script for getting all `.txt` files in a directory.

```
for ___,___,files in os.walk(some_folder):
    files[:]=[x for x in files if x.lower().endswith('txt')]
    for file in files:
```

Reading other questions on here a single underscore is normally used for throw away variables, is this use of a triple underscore just bad practice or is there significance to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single, double, triple and, in general, any amount of underscore only names in a script implicitly signifies that the value will not be used (the fact that it isn't given a "name" using any letters signifies this).

This is, of course, not set in stone (that is, Python doesn't treat `___` any differently than a name like `foo`) instead it's a convention programmers usually understand and respect.

The single underscore has a purpose only in interactive mode and it's the one that's employed in scripts instead of `__` or `___`. Using `___` and `__`  just look ugly and really are completely unecessary; I can't see why someone would decide to use it over `_`; don't copy them and opt for `_` when you need to get the same message across.

Comment: Thanks, am I right in thinking the [:] on line 2 is also redundant?

Comment: @Notts90 that changes `files` in-place; I'm not sure why the author decided they need to do that so I'd agree that, from what I can see, it's redundant.

Comment: One common reason to use `__` instead of `_` is if you are using gettext where `_` is commonly the translation function.

Answer (score 3):

Like Jim said, the `___` syntax usually means whatever is captured by that name (`___`) isn't useful, or is garbage. Take a look at the following example, for the sake of completeness:

I have a folder, `test`, with the following structure:

```
test
    subtest1
        file1.txt
        file2.txt
    subtest2
        file3.txt
```

Look what happens when I use `os.walk` on `test`:

```
>>> list(os.walk('test'))
[('test', ['subtest1', 'subtest2'], ['.DS_Store']), ('test/subtest1', [], ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']), ('test/subtest2', [], ['file3.txt'])]
>>> len(list(os.walk('test')))
3
```

So there are technically three elements in the generator returned by `os.walk('test')`. How many elements are within each element, though, since we clearly see some nested data structures?

```
>>> [len(x) for x in os.walk('test')]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Okay, there are three subelements in each element of `os.walk('test')`. For example, at `list(os.walk('test'))[0]`, there is `'test'` (the first element), `['subtest1', 'subtest2']` (the second element), and `['.DS_Store']` (the third and final element). The last element contains the non-directory files in whatever folder is denoted by the first element (so .DS_Store is a file in the `test` directory).

Let's get to your `for` loop, then (I won't use the underscores yet):

```
>>> for main_dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk('test'):
...         print("Main directory: ", main_dir)
...         print("Sub-directories: ", ', '.join(sub_dirs))
...         print("Files: ", ', '.join(files))
... 
Main directory:  test
Sub-directories:  subtest1, subtest2
Files:  .DS_Store
Main directory:  test/subtest1
Sub-directories:  
Files:  file1.txt, file2.txt
Main directory:  test/subtest2
Sub-directories:  
Files:  file3.txt
```

So the `for main_dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk('test')` syntax is really what we call "unpacking." We are assigning to `main_dir` the first element in `os.walk('test')`, to `sub_dirs` the second element, etc. The `___` syntax (which really should be just `_`), says to the reader, "Forget about these values; I've named the ones I need." In your case, the code is saying, "Forget about the directories from which these files come; I just want the filenames themselves."